# Specifying a homepage for a dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I'm working on a dynamic web project in eclipse ee, and i couldn't figure out where to specify the homepage, i.e. the page which is displayed first when I deploy the project to the server. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Specify a welcome file in your `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>FirstJSP.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.jsp should map to this by default, or you can use  as mentioned in some other answers.